# MYSQL: Trigger don't Update the last row in table with the value of another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created the trigger to Update the "request" table whenever the value is inserted into other table - "user". The column that must be updated is "UserID" with the value of "ID":

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `database`.`user_AFTER_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE request SET UserID = new.ID
  where id = (select * from (select max(id) from request) as t);
END
```

But, the code is not updating the last row, it is updating the row before the last one, please see the screenshots:

user table:
[image: user table]

request table:
[image: request table]

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: try `... SET UserID = new.ID where id = (select max(id) from request)`

Comment: thanks for your comment, @vaso123. However my code of web app (C# asp.net) is throwing an error when I use the line that you suggested:
NHibernate.AssertionFailure: 'null id in ACCDataStore.Entity.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)'

Comment: I am really new in Entittyframeworks and triggers, I am learning it just days ago :)

Comment: Try: `... where id = (select id from (select max(id) id from request) as t);`.

Comment: @wchiquito, thanks for suggestion, the error of NHibernate.AssertionFailure gone, but still only the row before last is updated - not the last row of request table((

Comment: When are the records created in the `request` table?. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qedU5b5jQAWMd4P7dFkQ2x/0).

Comment: @wchiquito, the records in "request" table are created at the same time as in "user" table, the values are inserted by my app done in asp.net. Hope that will help.